# How to embed with iframe python.org?

Tags: html, iframe

I have:

```
<iframe src="https://www.python.org/" width="900" height="900"> 
</iframe>
```

But I get a blank screen on both Firefox and Chrome. I can embed a map from google maps using similar markup, and it works on both browsers. I am a beginner, so I suppose I am missing something obvious. What is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Technical reason : python.org doesn't want to exists inside an iframe. Therefore, they use javascript to clear the page when an iframe is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP Header Field X-Frame-Options,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">
```

There are three possible values for X-Frame-Options:

`DENY` - The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

`SAMEORIGIN` - The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

`ALLOW-FROM uri` - The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.

so looks like the url has set `'X-Frame-Options'` to `'SAMEORIGIN'`.

> Refused to display 'https://www.python.org/' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Your server to disallow **other** webpages emebeding of Your webpages (like python did).

`Refused to display 'https://www.python.org/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)